# mod_rewrite with exceptions

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

For redirecting every request on my server to a secure connection I use

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

which works perfect.

However I need two paths not to be redirected.

Say when I access

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/page1/test
http://www.mywebsite.com/page2
```

I want to go to exactly that path. Is that possible with mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/page1/test
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/page2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```